# How can we find the closed form of this?

Tags: limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}k\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor\right)$$
I think it is equal to $2(\frac13 - \frac14 + \frac15 - \frac16 + \cdots)$, but does it have closed form?

Comment: It looks like the prime count of a central binomial coefficient, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Try to use Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\lfloor\frac{2n}k\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor$ evaluates to $0$ if $n$ (mod $k) < k/2$, and to $1$ if $n$ (mod $k) \ge k/2$. So the sum counts the number of $k \le n$ such that $n$ (mod $k) \ge k/2$.

For large $n$, this is approximately true for $\frac12n < k < \frac23n$, for $\frac13n < k < \frac25n$, for $\frac14n < k < \frac27n,\ldots$

So the proportion of such $k$ tends to $(\frac23 - \frac12) + (\frac25 - \frac13) + (\frac27-\frac14) = 2(\frac13 - \frac14 + \frac15 - \frac16 + \cdots)$, as you say.

And $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots = \log 2$. So your limit is $2\log 2 - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we use Riemann sums we get

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}k\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor\right) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2}x\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac 1 x\right\rfloor\right)dx .$$

You need to evaluate the last integral.

Comment: But evaluating that integral requires evaluating the sum, doesn't it?

Comment: @TonyK: No! There are techniques that can be used to evaluate the integral!

Comment: Could you elaborate, please ? I never faced such integrals (among many things I never faced). Thank you.